# Simplest possible use of STStrMap.poke in purescript

Tags: purescript

I'm trying to use the STStrMap purescript module to maintain a map for a long running server application. It's a very simple String map. Here is what I have so far:

```
import Data.StrMap.ST (new, STStrMap, poke)
import Control.Monad.ST (ST, runST)

type MyMap = forall h e. Eff ( st :: ST h | e) (STStrMap h String)

myMap :: MyMap
myMap = new

-- pokeAString :: String -> String -> MyMap ??
pokeAString k v = poke k v myMap
```

The signature of `MyMap` is `Eff`, but poke expects a `STStrMap` as the first parameter. I'm not sure how to code this correctly. Note: I'm a newbie to purescript.

Answer (score 1):

The STStrMap you initialize has side effects tracked by the Eff monad, so we have to use its instance of bind to run our computations (e.g. peek, poke), which has the type:

```
forall e a b. Eff e a -> (a -> Eff e b) -> Eff e b
```

In psci you can see how this works:

```
import Prelude
import Data.StrMap.ST

let myMap = new
let myPoke x = x >>= (\m -> poke m "key" "value")
let myPeek x = x >>= (\m -> peek m "key")
myPeek $ myPoke myMap
```

So your code becomes something like:

```
import Prelude
import Data.StrMap.ST (new, STStrMap, poke)
import Control.Monad.ST (ST)
import Control.Monad.Eff (Eff)

type MyMap = forall h e. Eff ( st :: ST h | e) (STStrMap h String)

myMap :: MyMap
myMap = new

pokeAString :: String -> String -> MyMap
pokeAString k v = do
  a <- myMap
  poke a k v
```